# Tengo un problema que me da con el if no funciona no se activa el bloque de abajo del if

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
print("hola bienvenido a la calculadora de areas")
print("Podemos calcular la area del triabgulo1 quadrado2 círculo4")
que=input("Quina area vols calcular? ")
if  que==1 :
  a=input('Di la mida de la base del triangulo: ') 
  b=input('Di la altura del mismo triangulo:') 
  total=(int(a)*int(b)/2) 
  print ('el resultado es: ') 
  print(total)
```

Comment: Se debe a que `input()`, en Python3, siempre te retorna resultados de tipo cadena (`str`), pero tú estás comparando `que` con un entero (`int`). Para arreglarlo o bien haces `if que == "1"`, para que lo compare con cadena, o bien haces `que = int(que)` tras leerlo, para convertirlo en entero (aunque esto puede fallar si el usuario teclea algo que no pueda ser interpretado como entero, tal como una letra).

Comment: muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 1):

Desde [programiz.com](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/input):

> El método input() lee una línea desde el teclado, la convierte en string y la retorna.

No funciona por que la variable `que` no es igual a `1`, si no que es igual a `'1'`. Ahora tienes dos opciones:

```
que = int(input("Quina area vols calcular? ")) # int() convierte un texto a un número.
if que == 1:
```

O simplemente:

```
que = input("Quina area vols calcular? ")
if que == '1': # 1 (número) no es igual a '1' (texto)
```